# How do I set a maximum image height in Docbook?

Tags: xml, image, docbook

I'm currently having an issue that when I convert my docbook to pdf, the images are a tad wonky.  90% of my screenshots are fine, but the remainders have a height beyond 740 pixels and this causes them to run off the page.  I'm having no problems with width.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xml:id="newNote">
  <title>New Note</title>
  <section>
    <title>Screenshot</title>
    <mediaobject>
      <imageobject>
        <imagedata fileref="./views/screenshots/newNote.png" scalefit="1" width="100%" contentdepth="100%"/>
      </imageobject>
    </mediaobject>
  </section>
</section>
```

I've tried `contentdepth="740"` and `contentdepth="740px"  width="100%"` But no luck.
I'm looking to tell the image to have a max height but fill out the width.

Comment: This is an specific XML vocabulary (DocBook) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what DocBook implementation you are using,  I would recommend setting the height of the viewport area using the depth attribute (depth="740px") to make sure that the scaling works as expected. And try smaller values (ie. 320px) to make sure you are not overflowing the page size.

If that doesn't do the trick, you may be experiencing a bug in the implementation.

Comment: I've tried depth="740px" with no luck.  But for some reason depth="6.5in" works, although I feel thats a lot more arbritary way of sizing

Comment: Perhaps 6.5in is scaling the image small enough to fit where 740px is just too large.  Depends on the dpi factor used by the implementation.  Again, hard to tell without knowing what you are using to render.